# Calling an array item into another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I faced the following functions (or method I don't what is right name of the ):

```
function getRowArray($scope, object, i){    
  i = i + 1;
  var item = {};
  var data = [];
  var id = -1;    

  if ($scope.selectedType !== undefined) {
    id = $scope.selectedType.id;
  }    

  var rating = getRating($scope, object, id);    
  item['name'] = $scope.objectInfo[object]['name'];
  item['objectId'] = rating.objectId;
  item['hideRating'] = parseInt($scope.objectInfo[object].hideControls) & 1;   
  item['addInfo'] = rating.addInfo;   
  item['rating'] = rating.value;    
  item['ratingId'] = rating.id;

  for (var i in $scope.objectInfo[object].childs) {        
    if ($scope.objectInfo[object].childs[i] == object){
        continue;
    }

    data.push(getRowArray($scope, $scope.objectInfo[object].childs[i], i));
  }    
  item['data'] = data;
  return item;
}
```

and

```
function getTypeRow($scope, oobject, otype){

  var item = {};
  var data = [];
  var rating = getRating($scope, oobject.id, otype.id);

  item['name'] = otype.name;
  item['objectId'] = rating.objectId;
  item['typeId'] = rating.typeId;
  item['ratingId'] = rating.id;
  item['addInfo'] = rating.addInfo;
  item['rating'] = rating.value;
  // item['hideRating'] = parseInt($scope.objectInfo[object].hideControls);

  return item;
}
```

I want to use the hideRating item from the first one in the second, I tried and added the commented line but I got an error it says the object is undifined, is it wrong like that or am I missing something ? thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you're spelling it `oobject` in your arguments list, but you're calling the function on an `object`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: the error is in the line i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is undefined because it wasn't initialized; it's not specified in the parameter list for the function `getTypeRow`. The `oobject` in the parameter list should be corrected to `object`:

```
// Correct 'oobject' to 'object'
function getTypeRow($scope, object, otype){

  var item = {};
  var data = [];
  // Correct 'oobject' to 'object'
  var rating = getRating($scope, oobject.id, otype.id);

  ...
}
```